# Strange type of password in mysql workbench

Tags: java, mysql, passwords, workbench

I have a problem with password which I get when some password is inputed in `JPasswordField`.

```
kasirlozinka = new JPasswordField("lozinka");
final String lozinka = new String(kasirlozinka.getPassword().toString());
```

And when I write a password like `"lozinka"` in mysql workbench I get something like `"[C@3f528528"`, so my questions are, how to fix this and get user input in string, and what type of password is this, how to decrypt it?

Comment: Why do you call `new String()`? `toString()` is already returning a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to [`JPasswordField.getPassword()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getPassword%28%29) returns a `char[]` (and you don't want to call `toString()` on that, because array doesn't override `Object.toString`). You can use [`String.valueOf(char[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28char[]%29) to make that a `String`. Something like,

```
char[] pass = kasirlozinka.getPassword();
String pw = String.valueOf(pass);
```

Answer (score 0):

`"[C@3f528528"` is a `String` representation of a `char[]`. `getPassword()` returns an array of `char`. Just remove `toString`:

```
final String lozinka = new String(kasirlozinka.getPassword());
```

Comment: When I remove `toString` I get label of JPasswordField .

Comment: when you remove `toString` you will get `kasirlozinka.getPassword()` which is an array of chars representing your password.

Answer (score 0):

`JPasswordField.getPassword()` returns a `char[]`. Calling `toString()` on an array will yield what you see.

To convert the password to a string, remove the `toString()`:

```
final String lozinka = new String(kasirlozinka.getPassword());
```

This will call the [new String(char[])](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28char[]%29) constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The toString() should be removed. 
kasirlozinka.getPassword() returns char[] which can be passed into a String constructor :

```
kasirlozinka = new JPasswordField("lozinka");
//final String lozinka = new String(kasirlozinka.getPassword().toString());
final String lozinka = new String(kasirlozinka.getPassword());
```